# Download Files From Google Drive Using Python

Tags: python, api, download

I want to download file from google drive directly using python. I had tried many module's like pydrive, google drive API, gdown, googledrivefiledownloader and many more but it always throw me error. When i use gdown module to download any type of file it's work perfectly but when i open that downloaded file it's show file is not supported.

I had tried this code as following

[This is following code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PmGT.png)

Comment: Share the attempt you have done. As of this description, no one can see what is the problem you are facing. Downloading a file using the google api client works fine

Comment: import gdown,
# here url is shareable link of file,
#here 1bHI9p8kTBsu6n5uGWCfq8ZwF-RqwpeJc is file id,
url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/uc?id=1bHI9p8kTBsu6n5uGWCfq8ZwF-RqwpeJc/view',
output = 'gdrive.zip',
gdown.download(url, output, quiet=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:-

```
from zdrive import Downloader

output_directory = "/home/abhinav/Documents"
d = Downloader()

# folder which want to download from Drive
folder_id = 'XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ'
d.downloadFolder(folder_id, destinationFolder=output_directory)
```

Comment: Giving me this error :- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\CA-SOFTWARES-main\CA-SOFTWARES-main\Installation.py", line 1, in <module>
    from zdrive import Downloader
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\CA SOFTWARES\venv\lib\site-packages\zdrive\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from zdrive.download.downloader import Downloader
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\CA SOFTWARES\venv\lib\site-packages\zdrive\download\downloader.py", line 12, in <module>
    from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
ImportError: cannot import name 'SIGPIPE' from 'signal'

Comment: ok will try to find another solution

Comment: I had created a softwares for which i want to make program to install that software which i had uploaded on google drive.